# Create Custom Window in Geocortex HTML Viewer

Tags: html, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to migrate my Asp.Net application to Geocortex Web viewer. I am going through all the documentation but no luck in finding a documentation regarding custom html window for a button in the toolbar. Could anyone please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you, you need to create a workflow module. and then add it to your menu icons (toolbar) using the admin GUI application of Geocortex.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It hurts me to say, but this is not an answer.

Comment: Workflow modules is iframe windows which looks like alert boxes(from my understanding). I need to create to rich html windows that compliments the design of the viewer. Could you provide more details.